# Python parse XML variables from a single tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that looks like the code below:

```
<spotter num="0187" report_at="2014-03-15 20:10:25" lat="49.8696518" lng="-80.0973129"callsign="wxman132" active="1" public="" gps="0" phone="" email="addu@nnu.nne" first="" last=""></spotter>
```

I've tried using dom.minidom, but how can I easily parse out the lat and lng variable values from the XML file?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an XML parser, like [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de).

Here's an example using `ElementTree` from the standard library:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring("""
<test>
    <spotter num="0187" report_at="2014-03-15 20:10:25" lat="49.8696518" lng="-80.0973129" callsign="wxman132" active="1" public="" gps="0" phone="" email="addu@nnu.nne" first="" last=""/>
</test>""")
spotter = tree.find('.//spotter')
print spotter.attrib['lat'], spotter.attrib['lng']
```

Here's an example using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '<spotter num="0187" report_at="2014-03-15 20:10:25" lat="49.8696518" lng="-80.0973129" callsign="wxman132" active="1" public="" gps="0" phone="" email="addu@nnu.nne" first="" last=""/>'    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)    

spotter = soup.spotter
print spotter['lat'], spotter['lng']
```

Both print:

```
49.8696518 -80.0973129
```

`BeautifulSoup` is more forgiving, in terms of well-formed xml structure (see, I had to edit the xml a bit to make things work for `ElementTree`), and it's actually much easier to work with.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Pyparsing has a builtin method for extracting attributes from HTML tags, without having to build a complete object model for the whole page.

```
html = """
<spotter num="0187" report_at="2014-03-15 20:10:25" lat="49.8696518" lng="-80.0973129" callsign="wxman132" active="1" public="" gps="0" phone="" email="addu@nnu.nne" first="" last="">

I've tried using dom.minidom, but how can I easily parse out the lat and lng variable values fro
<spotter num="0188" report_at="2014-03-15 20:11:25" lat="59.8696518" lng="-82.0973129" callsign="wxman132" active="1" public="" gps="0" phone="" email="addu@nnu.nne" first="" last="">

"""

from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags

spotterTag, spotterEndTag = makeHTMLTags("spotter")

for spotter in spotterTag.searchString(html):
    print spotter.report_at
    print spotter.num
    print spotter.lat
    print spotter.lng
    print spotter.email
    print
```

Prints

```
2014-03-15 20:10:25
0187
49.8696518
-80.0973129
addu@nnu.nne

2014-03-15 20:11:25
0188
59.8696518
-82.0973129
addu@nnu.nne
```